# Get route pattern by route name in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5.3

In laravel 5.1, I was able to get the route path by route name, for example:

Defined Route:

```php
Route::post('users/{user_id}/delete', 'UserController@delete')->name('user:delete');
```

In laravel 5.1, when I tried the below method, It gave the route without any error If I didn't pass any route parameter:

```php
route('user:delete'); // Output: http://example.com/users/%7Buser_id%7D/delete
```

and then in javascript, I simply replaced %7Buser_id%7D with the user id dynamically. But laravel 5.3 is throwing error when accessing route by name that has parameters and I don't want to pass one, because the parameters are set dynamically from the javascript.

Is there any way I can access route pattern by route name like:

```
http://example.com/users/{user_id}/delete
```

Or

```
/users/{user_id}/delete
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure the parameter is set before accessing the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give some `route` method some value, that will be then replaced in javascript. For example: `route('user:delete', 'USER_ID')`, then in javascript you will simply replace USER_ID.

or the better way, is to use package called ["Laroute"](https://github.com/aaronlord/laroute)

Comment: how to user `Laroute` with dingo api routes?

Comment: You can use `Laroute` on every route, which has name. In your case like this: `laroute.route('user:delete', { user_id : 1 });`

Comment: I tried to generate the js file, but It only contains routes defined in `web.php` file, but doesn't include routes written in `api.php`, may be It's not including because I am using `dingo routes`.

Comment: Follow documentations. When you register route in `Laravel`, you will need to run `php artisan laroute:generate` this command to generate **Javascript** file with your routes. Don't forget this.

Comment: `php artisan route:list` this command shows you that **dingo routes**?

Comment: No, It doesn't, dingo routes has different command, `api:routes`

Comment: In that case laroute isn't for you

Comment: :-( Thanks for your help, will use the first way.